# How to change name/label of values returned in KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, wcf

We've create a WCF method that returns a KeyValuePair.  As is standard, the name or label of each field is either Key or Value.  Our BA is asking if that can be changed such that the service returns the names as CountyKey and CountyName rather than Key and Value.  Is this even possible?

[image]

Comment: You can always make and use a new class with those properties instead of the KVP.  Is that an unacceptable or undesirable solution?

Comment: Make a class with a `CountryKey` and `CountryName` property and use that instead. Otherwise, depending on how you are serializing stuff, you can change it there.

Comment: Depending on why they want this, perhaps it would be better to just capture the response into a property or field named `Country`. Then, for a property, you would have: `someObject.Country.Key` or for a local variable, it would just be `country.Key`.

Comment: @Amy and Matt I was trying to take the easy way but yes, you are both correct.  I will just have to create a new class in each of these instances.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to fill that requirement is to write a custom class that has those fields:

```
public class CountryKVP<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TKey CountryKey { get; }
    public TValue CountryValue { get; }

    public CountryKVP(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        CountryKey = key;
        CountryValue = value;
    }

    public CountryKVP(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> input)
    {
        CountryKey = input.Key;
        CountryValue = input.Value;
    }
}
```

Then, you can either pass this class from the WCF method directly:

```
CountryKVP<string, string> country = client.WebSvcThatReturnsCountryKVP();
```

Or, on the consuming side, you can initialize it by passing the returned `KeyValuePair` to the constructor:

```
var country = new CountryKVP<string, string>(client.WebSvcThatReturnsKVP);

// Now use the properties:
Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", country.CountryKey, country.CountryValue);
```

Also, since we're dealing with a single `KeyValuePair` here, normally you would just assign it to a property called `Country`, and then access the `Key` and `Value` like:

```
var someObject = new ObjectWithCountryProperty();

someObject.Country = client.WebSvcThatReturnsKVP();

// Now use the properties:
Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", someObject.Country.Key, someObject.Country.Value);
```